# replace all selected values as NaN in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df which looks like:

```
test1   test2   test3   test_Date       test5
285685  0000105 0   2016-11-25 00:00:00 
285685  0000106 0   2016-11-25 00:00:00 
285685  0000107 1   2016-11-25 00:00:00 
Null    NULL    #N/A    #DIV/0!
```

I am trying to populate something like this:

```
test1   test2   test3   test_Date       test5
285685  0000105 NaN 2016-11-25 00:00:00 NaN
285685  0000106 NaN 2016-11-25 00:00:00 NaN
285685  0000107 1   2016-11-25 00:00:00 NaN
NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN        NaN  NaN
```

Basically trying  to replace 0,'NA','NULL','#DIV/0!',' #VALUE','NaN','#N/A','#REF!',' (space)','0','Null' all to NaN

Using the below code I am not able to do it:

```
 f = dataframe.replace((0,'NA','NULL','#DIV/0!',' #VALUE','NaN','#N/A','#REF!',' ','0','Null'), np.nan).apply(lambda x: any(~x.isnull()))
 dataframe.loc[:,f]
```

I am getting the below output:

```
test1   test2   test3   test_Date
285685 0000105 0.0 2016-11-25 
285685 0000106 0.0 2016-11-25 
285685 0000107 1.0 2016-11-25 
Null   NaN        NaN NaT
```

I am losing one column as well named test5 and the values aren't getting replaced either.Need some help.

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use square brackets for your list of values to replace instead of parentheses, and omit the `.apply` at the end:

```
>>> df
    test1  test2  test3            test_Date test5
0  285685  105.0    0.0  2016-11-25 00:00:00      
1  285685  106.0    0.0  2016-11-25 00:00:00      
2  285685  107.0    1.0  2016-11-25 00:00:00      
3    Null    NaN    NaN              #DIV/0!     

>>> df.replace([0,'NA','NULL','#DIV/0!',' #VALUE','NaN','#N/A','#REF!',' ','0','Null'], np.nan)
    test1  test2  test3            test_Date  test5
0  285685  105.0    NaN  2016-11-25 00:00:00    NaN
1  285685  106.0    NaN  2016-11-25 00:00:00    NaN
2  285685  107.0    1.0  2016-11-25 00:00:00    NaN
3     NaN    NaN    NaN                  NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks much..!! :) God bless..!!

Comment: Would be really interested to know what went wrong there. :)

Comment: if you take a look at the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), it says that the argument `to_replace` can be a list, string, regex, etc..., but what you had supplied originally with the parentheses is a tuple (which is not an option). Square brackets specify `list` types instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you are reading this from a csv file, use the `na_values` argument.  See documentaion: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

```
read_csv(
    ...,
    na_values=[0,'NA','NULL','#DIV/0!',' #VALUE','NaN','#N/A','#REF!',' ','0','Null'],
    ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks much..!! This will certainly help. Right now i was reading from excel. Thanks again.

Comment: [`read_excel` also has an `na_values` argument](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)